# how to update the variable while changing the select option?

Tags: javascript, html

This is html page, which contains JavaScript and HTML code.

In this, if I select `'1'` then it will show the table which match with the `id '1'`.

The question is:

If I change the value into `'2'`, will it still keep the table value for `'1'` and afterwards adds value for number '2' to the table ?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <scripttype="text/javascript">
    window.onload   =functionmyfunction(val){
    vareSelect=document.getElementById('transfer_reason');
    varoptOtherReason=document.getElementById('otherdetail');
    varoptOtherReason1=document.getElementById('otherdetail1');
    varoptOtherReason2=document.getElementById('otherdetail2');
    varoptOtherReason3=document.getElementById('otherdetail3');
    varoptOtherReason4=document.getElementById('otherdetail4');
    varoptOtherReason5=document.getElementById('otherdetail5');
    eSelect.onchange=function()
    {   if(eSelect.selectedIndex===0)
        {
    optOtherReason.style.display='block';

    }

        elseif(eSelect.selectedIndex===1)
        {
    optOtherReason1.style.display='block';
    }

    elseif(eSelect.selectedIndex===2)
        {
    optOtherReason2.style.display='block';
    }
        elseif(eSelect.selectedIndex===3)
        {
    optOtherReason3.style.display='block';
    }

    elseif(eSelect.selectedIndex===4)
        {
    optOtherReason4.style.display='block';
    }
        elseif(eSelect.selectedIndex===5)
        {
    optOtherReason5.style.display='block';
    }
        else
        {
    optOtherReason.style.display='none';
    }
    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <selectid="transfer_reason"name="transfer_reason"onchange="myfunction(this.value);">
    <optionvalue="1">1</option>
    <optionvalue="2">2</option>
    <optionvalue="3">3</option>
    <optionvalue="4">4</option>
    <optionvalue="5">5</option>
    <optionvalue="6">6</option>
    <optionvalue="other">OtherReason</option>
    </select>
    <divid="otherdetail"style="display:none;">
    <tableborder="2"width="300"height="20">
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <divid="otherdetail1"style="display:none;">
    <tableborder="2"width="300"height="20">
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <divid="otherdetail2"style="display:none;">
    <tableborder="2"width="300"height="20">
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <divid="otherdetail3"style="display:none;">
    <tableborder="2"width="300"height="20">
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>       
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <divid="otherdetail4"style="display:none;">
    <tableborder="2"width="300"height="20">
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>       
    <td></td>
    <td></td>       
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <divid="otherdetail5"style="display:none;">
    <tableborder="2"width="300"height="20">
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to hide all tables at the start of myfunction like below

```
function myfunciton()
{

  // hide all tables first
  optOtherReason1.style.display='none';
  optOtherReason2.style.display='none'; 
  optOtherReason3.style.display='none';  
  optOtherReason4.style.display='none';// hide all tables whatever you have
}
```

Comment: you mean , hide the tables in front of the show function?

Comment: yes, you need to hide all tables first and then show table with selected option. this way only selected table will be visilble. You can put this code in some function lets say hideAllTable(){ hide all tables here } then call this function from myfunction() { hideAllTable()  ... and rest of your code}..

Comment: i did hide all the table by using style:display“none"

Comment: yeah thats correct, hide all tables at the begining of myfunction and keep rest of the code as it is

Comment: but the problem still there

Comment: can you post a JSFiddle for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the values before you set / update the new value.

**Example idea**

1. Set Table1 to `block`
2. Change to 2
3. Set Table1 to `none`
4. Set Table2 to `block`
5. ...

Comment: Bhushan Kawadkar posted my idea with a code example.